# not able to see user activity while being in sudo -i

Tags: linux

I usually execute "watch -n0.1 w" to see what user is continuously doing.
However, if the user executes "sudo -i", becomes root and executes something, I cannot see his activity anymore.

Take the following example:
I have 3 sessions open. On first session, I am checking "watch -n1 w" to see what other users are doing. On second session, I'm executing "sudo -i", then "vim session2.txt". On third session, I'm executing "vim session3.txt"

```
Every 1.0s: w

15:31:37 up 63 days,  3:54,  3 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.29, 0.26
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user1   pts/1    192.168.1.13     14:40    4.00s  0.50s  0.02s sshd: user1 [priv]
user1   pts/2    192.168.1.13     15:21    9:37   0.18s  0.02s sshd: user1 [priv]
user1   pts/3    192.168.1.13     15:24    7:21   0.14s  0.05s vim session3.txt
```

As you can see I cannot see that on session 2 the user is doing "vim session2.txt" (being in sudo -i), but I can see on session 3 that user is doing "vim session3.txt"

Comment: If you want to monitor the actions of users, watch is probably the *very* wrong way to do it.

Comment: why? watch is a great command, it refreshes the activity every second, so I can just watch the screen and see how he switches the commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see anyone running privileged commands using sudo in watch you need to run your watch in sudo as well. Try the following, it should work

```
sudo -S watch -n1 w
```

**Update**: Sorry, this answer only works on BSD :(

Comment: I am already root, however I've tested it though, and I still cannot see what user on session 2 is doing. Also sudo -S means "-S, --stdin                   read password from standard input".

Comment: Interesting... I had no problem seeing everything when I tried... what OS/distro you are running? As per your comment, yes, you need to use -S to see the password prompt from sudo so you can enter your password, otherwise it is difficult if not impossible to enter your password.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic, but I know for sure this is happening on other distros as well, like CentOS. You can't see what one user is doing while he is in "sudo -i" bash process, using "w" command. You would only see "sshd: <user_name> [priv]" as the command executed by him.

Comment: You are right. I am on a mac (BSD unix) that shows everything but the same thing doesn't work on a Linux. It is probably watch implementation that is not displaying the command executed under privileged runs in Linux while BSD does.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the "watch" command. Even if I type "w", I still cannot see what a user does while being in "sudo -i"